# Word Slider in Splash Screen Android

Tags: java, android, cpu-word, splash-screen, android-progressbar

I am trying to do an app in which there is a splash screen in the beginning. During loading, i need to show "Loading images...Loading modules....Now you are ready to go",etc. This is similar to the way in which facebook app loads showing the splash screen. I don't know how to do this. This is my current code :

```
    public class Splash extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    int logoTimer = 0;
                    while (logoTimer<5000){
                        sleep(100);
                        logoTimer=logoTimer+100;
                     }
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.package.MAIN"));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        logoTimer.start();
        }
   }
```

I would also like to keep a `ProgressBar` along with this. Can anyone help me out with a sample code or a reference. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use  [Handler](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) to communicate from background thread to UI thread. Handler should send messages to UI when loading of one module is finished.

Comment: :Can you give an example code to use handler to show the progress with the help of a progressbar while loading the url.

Comment: Check this [tuturial](http://idlesun.blogspot.com/2012/12/android-handler-and-message-tutorial.html). Your enum values could be 'IMG_END', 'MOD_END' . You instantiate 'progressBar' in standard way